# QIODevice::read (QFile, "..\widget_drawing\texture.data"): device not open when call QFile::close()

Tags: c++, qt

I use QFile and QDataStream to get data from file to memory like this

```
    file=new QFile("../widget_drawing/texture.data");
    int size=file->size();
    void* mem_texture=malloc(size);
    bool err=file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QDataStream out;
    out.setDevice(file);
    out.readRawData((char*)mem_texture,size);
    file->close();
```

Qt will report :QIODevice::read (QFile, "..\widget_drawing\texture.data"): device not open. But if I delete `file->close();`, this err disappeared. I checked `err=file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);`, err is true. So what cause the error message?

Comment: Calling `file->size();` before opening the file doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your .data file needs to be in your "working directory":https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory. Usually, this is the folder that contains your .exe file, not your .cpp files. Maybe in this case?

Comment: @vahancho file->size() will work correctly in this case, I debuged  and saw the value of size changed.